# Python 3.3.2 error indexing arrays

Tags: python

I am new to python and just need a tad of help with this test program I am using to revise my learning.

I am getting an error on the last question of this program:

```
var1 = [["Carl", 1], ["Josh", 3]]
input("Please choose var1[0] or var1[1]")
if input == var1[0]:
    input("would you like to print the string or the int?(0 = str, 1 = int)")
    if input == 0:
        print(var1[0[0]])
    else:
        print(var1[0[1]])

else:
    input("would you like to print the string or the int?(0 = str, 1 = int)")
    if input == 0:
        print(var1[1[0]])
    else:
        print(var1[1[1]])
```

Comment: You're looking for `var[0][0]` not `var[0[0]]`

Answer (score 4):

You have three problems:

1. You are indexing your array wrong.  The syntax should be like this: `print(var1[0][0])`
2. You need to compare the input with strings, since `input` returns a string object.
3. You need to assign that input to a variable so that you can use it later.  Right now, you are comparing with the *built-in* `input` itself.

---

Here is your code with those problems fixed:

```
var1 = [["Carl", 1], ["Josh", 3]]
user_input = input("Please choose var1[0] or var1[1]")
if user_input == var1[0]:
    user_input = input("would you like to print the string or the int?(0 = str, 1 = int)")
    if user_input == '0':
        print(var1[0][0])
    else:
        print(var1[0][1])

else:
    user_input = input("would you like to print the string or the int?(0 = str, 1 = int)")
    if user_input == '0':
        print(var1[1][0])
    else:
        print(var1[1][1])
```

Comment: That's what fast problem solving is ;-).

Comment: The result of `input("whatever")` doesn't seem to be assigned anywhere, and the comparisons are currently with the *function* `input`.

Comment: @user2980960 - Happy to help!  Don't forget to accept my answer (click the tick) so people know this question is answered.